# connect to hasura console using graphql playground

Tags: hasura, graphql-playground

I am having a difficult time using Hasura built-in GrpahQL manipulation UserInterface. so I decided to use the GrpahQL playground as I used to. but when I try to access the exact graphql endpoint. there is an error appears on the playground.

```
 Unexpected token p in JSON at position 4
```

I have also placed my Hasura admin secret in the HTTP headers section.

```
{
  "x-hasura-admin-secret": "myadminsecretkey",
  "content-type": "application/json"
}
```

[image: can't access Hasura console from graphql playground]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphQL endpoint that Hasura serves would be available at `/v1/graphql`.

So in your case, it would be `http://localhost:9695/v1/graphql`.

Comment: Thank you. I had to use the http://localhost:3030/v1/graphql 
even though the console was serving with the port 9695
the endpoint Hasura using was clearly visible in the Hasura interface in the GraphQL Endpoint section.